# Inserting rows to other tables while importing in SSIS

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, multiple-tables

I have a transactions table in a `flat file` like

```
ItemID ,ItemName ,CustomerID ,CustomerName ,Qty ,Price ,TotalValue
```

and `target` transaction table will have

```
ItemID,CustomerID,Qty,Price,TotalValue
```

Now I have to import it into the transactions table using SSIS package

But before importing `ItemID` and `CustomerID` I should look into the `lookup` tables `ItemMaster` and `CustomerMaster`, if not there, then I have insert new tuples into the tables and take the new `itemID` or `customerID` and import the transaction to the transactions table. It can be done using lookup transformations in SSIS.

Or is it better to import transactions into a temporary table using a SSIS package ,update new `ItemIDs` and `customer IDs` in the temporary table and then insert transactions from the temp table to the main transactions table

Which option will be better from the performance wise ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways of doing it .

1.Using Staging Table

2.Using Lookup

3.Transforming the stored procedure logic in SSIS

1.`Using Staging Table`

Dump all the flat file data into a staging table .Lets name it as `StgTransaction`.Create a procedure to perform the tasks .

```
 Merge ItemMaster target
 using StgTransaction src
 on target.ItemID = src.ItemID
 WHEN NOT MATCHED  THEN 
 INSERT (ItemName)
 values (src.ItemID);

 Merge CustomerMaster target
 using Trans src
 on target.CustomerID = Src.CustomerID
 WHEN NOT MATCHED  THEN 
 INSERT (CustomerName)
 values (src.CustomerID);

with cte(ItemID ,ItemName ,CustomerID ,CustomerName ,Qty ,Price ,TotalValue) as 
 (
    Select I.ItemID,I.ItemName,
               C.CustomerID,C.CustomerName,
               f.Qty,f.price,f.TotalValue
    from ItemMaster I inner join Trans f
     on I.ItemName = f.ItemName
    inner join CustomerMaster c
    on c.CustomerName = f.CustomerName
)
Insert into Transactions
Select ItemID ,ItemName ,CustomerID ,CustomerName ,Qty ,Price ,TotalValue
from cte
```

Basically I'm inserting all the missing values into the 2 master tables using [Merge](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/the-merge-statement-in-sql-server-2008/) Syntax .Instead of Merge you can use `NOT EXISTS`

```
 Insert into ItemMaster 
 Select ItemName from stgTransaction s
 where not exists 
              (Select 1 from ItemMaster im 
               where im.ItemName = s.ItemName
              );
```

Once the `missing` values are inserted then just join the staging table with the 2 `master` tables and insert it into `target` .

Wrap the above query into a `procedure` and call the procedure after the `Data Flow Task` (Which loads the Data from `flat file` to `staging table`)

2.Using Lookup

The package design will look like

[image]

You should go with this approach if you are not allowed to create staging table in your database . This will be slow because of blocking components (Union ALL) and OlEDB command(problem with RBAR (row by agonizing row) issue)

Steps :-
1.Use `lookup` with `ItemMaster` table

[image]

2.Create a `ItemID` column (name it as NewItemID) using `Derived transformation` which will store the new ItemID generated from ItemMaster table when the data is loaded .join Lookup with Derived Transformation using `No Match Output`

[image]

3.The No Matched values should be inserted into ItemMaster table.For this lets create a procedure which inserts the data and retrieves the ItemID value as an `Output`

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE usp_InsertMaster
 @ItemName AS varchar(20),
 @id AS INT OUTPUT AS
 INSERT INTO ItemMaster
 (ItemName) 
  VALUES 
 (@ItemName)
 SET @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()  
 //If your using ID as Identity value else use Output clause to retrieve the ID
```

3.Call this procedure in OLEDB command and map the output with the column created in Derived transformation

[image]

[image]

4. After the `OLEDB command` using `Union ALL` to combine the rows from `matched` and `No Matched values` and then again follow the same procedure with the `CustomerMaster` table

[image]

3.Last option is `Transforming procedure` logic in `SSIS`

Package Design is

[image]

1.Load the data into staging

2.Use `Merge` or `Not Exists` and load the missing values in 2 Master tables using `Execute SQL Task`

3.Use Data Flow Task with source as Staging and  2 lookups with  the master tables .Since all the missing values are already inserted into Master tables ,so there wont be any `Lookup No match Output`. Just connect the Lookup Match output with Oledb Destination (Transaction Table)

IMHO i think the `1st` approach will be `fast` . The problem arises only because there are 2 master tables which needs to be updated along with that get the inserted ID's and load it into target table.So doing it `synchronously` is difficult .

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Yes, first option will be faster. I am think to calculate time required usng SSIS and Merging. How can we know exact time taken by SSIS package ?

Comment: You can see the result using execution tab in SSIS or else i generally prefer [BIDS HELPER](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com) to get the detailed execution result for individual components